# Symfony 4 Unable to write on cache/dev directory

Tags: symfony, vagrant

I've setup a new symfony 4 project. This is running on vagrant for local development. Now I'm running into file permission issues.

Symfony itself says it should be any problem: [Setting up or Fixing File Permissions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html).

If I run `bin/console cache:clear`, the code is running fine. But once I change my code, I'm getting the following error:

```
(1/1) IOException
Unable to write to the "/var/www/path_to_project/var/cache/dev" directory.
```

Running `bin/console cache:clear` again, code works fine. But changing the code again, same write issue again.

I tried to `chmod +r 777 var/cache/dev`, but that doesn't change a thing. How can I fix this?

Output for **Ahmed bhs**

```
$ ls -la var/
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  4 vagrant vagrant 136 Jan  7 11:41 ./
drwxrwxr-x 14 vagrant vagrant 476 Jan  7 12:30 ../
drwxrwxr-x  3 vagrant vagrant 102 Jan  7 12:57 cache/
drwxrwxr-x  2 vagrant vagrant  68 Jan  7 11:41 log/

$ id
uid=1000(vagrant) gid=1000(vagrant) groups=1000(vagrant),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),33(www-data),46(plugdev),110(lxd),115(lpadmin),116(sambashare),998(rvm),1003(www-user)
```

**EDIT**
The problem wasn't symfony but the configuration of my vagrantfile.
Synced_folder had owner 'vagrant' while apache 'www-data'. Made all 'www-data' and now it is working fine. Totally not symfony related!

Comment: Try `chown -R $USER:$USER var/`

Comment: Also remove `var/cache/dev` folder manually just in case.

Comment: Normally this sould affect `var/` and his subdirectories

Comment: @Ahmedbhs, doesn't work, also removing the folder has no effect.

Comment: Could you give just type: `ls -la var/ ` and then `id` and show us the results

Comment: @Ahmedbhs, see my edit

Answer (score 3):

Try

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/path_to_project/var/cache/*`

Answer (score 1):

Run `chmod -R 0777 var` instead of running commands for separate folders.

Comment: in vagrant you need to set-up permissions in vagrant configuration (or yml) file instead

Comment: What should the permission configuration be?

Comment: `        synced_folder:
            folder1:
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
                source: ./
                target: /var/www/wealthbot
                sync_type: default
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                    mount_options:
                        dir_mode: '0775'
                        file_mode: '0664'
`

Comment: maybe you need more detailed configuration.
also check 0777 config

Comment: Yes found te problem, vagrant related. synced_folder had owner 'vagrant' while apache 'www-data'. Made all 'www-data' and now it is working fine. Totally not symfony related! Tnx

Comment: @Timo002 could just post a clear solution and how you resolve the issue please

Comment: @Timo002 just use www-data user and group for www folder

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem for Symfony 6, but I think it is also relevant.
You need to change the `cache` directory to an unmounted path.
Add to `src/Kernel.php`:

```
class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    public function getCacheDir(): string
    {
        if ($this->getEnvironment() === 'local') {
            return '/tmp/mail-service/' . $this->getEnvironment() . '/cache';
        } else {
            return parent::getCacheDir();
        }
    }
}
```

And add to project root file `.env.local`:

```
APP_ENV=local
```